# Why does the same code line sometimes Easy load and sometimes Eager Load (.Net C#)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Working on a WPF application using Entity Framework.

I have an entity MyClass1 linked to MyClass2 more or less this way:

```
public class MyClass1
{
...
 List<MyClass2> mc2s {get; set;}
}
```

My Context has a DBSet of each class:

```
...
public DbSet<MyClass1> C1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<MyClass2> C2 { get; set; }
```

In my DBInitialize.Seed() function:
after running this line:

```
 List<MyClass1> list1= new List<MyClass1>(context.C1);
```

I can see that the mc2s property of all list1 elements is correctly populated (eager loading).

Then I have to run the exact same line in a different part of the program (into a ViewModel):

```
  List<MyClass1> list1= new List<MyClass1>(context.C1);
```

And in this emplacement, if easy loads and all my list elements mc2s property = null.

Where does the difference come from?

I tried to type

```
 context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

before, but it did not make any difference.

I suppose that it is a consequence of the Context obect being different in both invokation ?

Answer (score 1):

I found it out.
In DBInitialize.Seed(), the context had already (fully) loaded the MyClass1 instances so the mc2s property was ready to be used.

If in  DBInitialize.Seed() I later declare a second (new) context, then it easy loads too.
All makes sense now :)